# Eigenvalues of $AA^T$ given that $A \in \mathbb{M}_{3\times 3}(\mathbb{R})$ satisifies $\det(A)=1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I feel like the solution to this ought to be simple but I'm getting a consistently incorrect answer so hopefully one of you guys can shed some insight. The matrix $AA^T$ is real and symmetric so its eigenvalues should also be real. The characteristic polynomial of $AA^T$ is
$$\det(AA^T - \lambda I) = -\lambda^3 + \text{tr}(AA^T)\lambda^2 - \text{tr}(\text{cof}(AA^T))\lambda + \det(AA^T). $$

Now, $\det(AA^T) = \det(A)\det(A^T) = 1$ so $AA^T$ is invertible, with

$$(AA^T)^{-1} = \text{cof}(AA^T)^T,$$

therefore

$$\text{tr}(\text{cof}(AA^T)) = \text{tr}((AA^T)^{-T}) = \text{tr}((AA^T)^{-1}) = \|A^{-1}\|^2 = \frac{1}{\|A\|^2}, $$
where here $\|\cdot\|$ is the Euclidean norm $\|A\|^2 = \sum_{i,j} a_{ij}^2 = \text{tr}(AA^T).$ Therefore our characteristic equation reduces to
$$\lambda^{3} - \|A\|^2\lambda^{2} + \frac{1}{\|A\|^2} \lambda - 1 = (\lambda - \|A\|^2)(\lambda^2+\frac{1}{\|A\|^2} ),$$
which clearly contradicts the eigenvalues all being real. Could anyone point out where I am going wrong with this?

Comment: I'm a little tired but is $\| A^{-1} \|^2 = \frac1{\|A\|^2}$ right?

Comment: No, it's not right. Try a $2\times 2$ diagonal matrix.

Comment: Damn yeah I see that now, silly error on my part. I'd just 'normed' both sides of $AA^{-1} = I$ but there's a bunch wrong with that.  Thanks for your help, I'll keep working at it!

Comment: I think about all you could say about the eigenvalues is that they're all positive real, and their product is 1.  (For any $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ satisfying these conditions, you can have $A = \operatorname{diag}(\sqrt{\lambda_1}, \sqrt{\lambda_2}, \sqrt{\lambda_3})$.)

Comment: In practice for my purposes $A$ is actually the Jacobian matrix of a particular map you can explicitly define so likely I'll be able to use properties of that function to find the eigenvalues, I was just looking for a shortcut to avoid some calculation really

Comment: @DanielSchepler I think your comment should be edited as an anwer.